# Which is the best font for Console/Terminal/Command Prompt in Linux/Windows?

Tags: command-line, terminal, fonts, console

I have seen `Consolas` as very good programming font.

But I don't think the same font looks very good in Console and Terminal.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming - There's many console/programming font questions and recommendations over there. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'm a stickler for [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/). It's not a fancy font, but then again that's the point.

Comment: The link no longer points to the correct website. Here's the current one: https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/